# Is there an R function for recognizing a number as a missing value?

Tags: r, null, statistics, missing-data

I am working with Mplus for data analyses so I'd like to keep my missing values coded as -999. However, I'm using R to check some assumptions and it's skewing all of my data. I was wondering if there was a simple line of code like Mplus uses where it says MISSING ARE ALL (-999) but for R so I don't have to change all the values to NA column by column.

Thanks!

Comment: `dplyr::na_if` across all relevant columns? Or set an `NA` argument in however you're reading in the data. Try to make a [mcve] so it's easier to help

Comment: I used the na = "-999" function within read.csv when reading in the data - definitely did not remember that was a thing! Thank you so much.

Comment: You should rephrase your comment as an answer. And Accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could reference anything but the -999 values using

```
DataFrame[!DataFrame$DataColumn == -999, ]
```

This will basically make R ignore anything that has a -999 value for that particular analysis. Alternatively, you can remove all -999 values simply by using this line.

```
DataFrame <- DataFrame[!DataFrame$DataColumn == -999, ]
```

Comment: Or set the -999 to NA. `DataFrame[DataFrame$DataColumn == -999, ] = NA`